# Does a cotton blanket for daytime use need tzitzis?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, daytime

Regarding blankets, standard practice is that we don't attach tzitzis and we don't round off any corners.

Reddit user ShamanSTK [asks](http://www.reddit.com/r/Judaism/comments/16jz2u/halacha_hypo_tzitzis_on_a_blanket/):

> I have a blanket on the couch with four corners which is almost used exclusively for day time use. It is not a blanket slept with and it is used solely for warmth when I don't feel like turning on the heat. Does it need tzitzis?

In the case of a wool blanket in the daytime, this link says to [round one corner](http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/mb/10mb.htm). What if ShamanSTK's blanket is made of cotton? Must he round one corner? Must he attach tzitzis?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed one does not attach tzitzit to a blanket, whether cotton or wool

[R Jonathan Blass](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=111) at yeshiva.co notes

> **It does not need Tzitzit** (Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayim 18, 2). Some say
>   the reason is because the main use of the blanket and sheet is at
>   night; others explain that only something worn as a garment needs
>   Tzitzit (Mishna Berura 18, 8)

A cotton blanket is certainly exempt. [halacha.co](http://halacha.co/en/tzitzis-on-blankets/) explains

> Based on the Gemara, some rishonim claim that the term “garment” in
>   the Torah is reserved for wool and linen, and other materials are only
>   obligated mid'rabanan, while others argue.
>
> **Tradition is not to place tzitzis on blankets** due to a combination of
>   two exemptions: it is primarily for night use, and it is not worn.
>   Nonetheless the Alter Rebbe [rules](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3269370/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-18-Times-at-which-the-Mitzvah-of-Tzitzis-Applies.htm) one should round a corner of a
>   woolen blanket.